# Window.open not displaying anything after adding iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to open a new window using `window.open` with dynamic content (for print functionality I am using this dynamic content).
Below dynamic HTML is not visible on `window.open` page where as in view source it is available. Please help me out why it is not getting displayed there.

Below is the code.

```
var win = window.open('', 'title', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=yes,width=' + (screen.width - 100) + ',   height=' + (screen.height - 150));

win.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>");

win.document.write("<html>");
win.document.write("<head><title>title</title>");
win.document.write('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">function printPage() { PrintDiv("defaultPrintBuffer"); }<\/script>');
win.document.write('</head>');

win.document.write('<body>');

win.document.write("<iframe  width='560' height='315' id='defaultPrintBuffer2' name='defaultPrintBuffer2'>");
win.document.write(iframeContent);
win.document.write("</iframe>");
win.document.write('</body>');

win.document.write("</html>");

win.document.close();

win.focus();
win.printPage();
```

Comment: You can just put all the static parts of the new page you're creating in a seperate html file and open that file. This way you don't have to use document.write and can just set the url or content of the iframe the normal way. But to answer your question, your script tag is not closed properly: `<\/script>`

Comment: I have generated the iframe using jquery, there is no url in the iframe src. I am implementing print functionality and trying to achieving using IFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that you're trying to implement printing, I'll add how I solved this problem in an answer instead of a comment, so the code is more readable.
Basically I made an empty (but valid) html page and just insert nodes into that page before printing it. This avoids the use of document.write and iframes, which are considered bad practice in alot of cases. If you really want to use an iframe, just add the iframe to the print page html and append your content to that node instead of to the body.

```
var data = $('myPartOfPageSelector'),
    printPage;
if (!data || !data.length) alert('Nothing to print.');
else {
    printPage = window.open('resources/print.html');
    setTimeout(function() {
        printPage.document.body.innerHTML = data.innerHTML;
        printPage.print();
        printPage.close();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, it seems it will work but Please suggest me how to add iframe in print.html as i will give print of iframe not complete page.

Comment: This is perfect answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` tag doesn't show the content that you put in it, you have to load a page in the iframe.

You could use a script to put content in the iframe:

```
win.document.write("<iframe  width='560' height='315' id='defaultPrintBuffer2' name='defaultPrintBuffer2'>");
win.document.write("</iframe>");
win.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>var doc = document.getElementById('defaultPrintBuffer2').contentWindow.document;doc.open();doc.write('" + iframeContent.replace("'","\\'").replace("\\","\\\\") + "');doc.close();</script>");
```

Note that the content should be a complete HTML document in itself.

Comment: It is throwing an error 
TypeError: doc.write is not a function

Comment: @user2078643: I missed the `.document` at the end to get the document object from the window. I updated the code above.